# Sorting a JSON response data in Angular 8

Tags: angular, sorting, syntax, frontend, angular8

I have to sort the response JSON data as per the approved status. Response data is something like this;
[0]:
adjustmnetfileds: Array(2)
[0]: some data
[2]: some data

adjustments : Array(1)
0:
approvedByName: 'Jack'
taskName: 'Insurance'
**approvedStatus**: 1

[2]:
adjustmnetfileds: Array(2)
[0]: some data
[2]: some data

adjustments : Array(1)
0:
approvedByName: 'Dan'
taskName: 'Insurance-Test'
**approvedStatus**: 2

JSON response is something like this (nested arrays) and I want to sort the response as per the "approvedStatus (either asc or desc).
Snapshot attached for reference.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Read [ask] question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method by providing your custom compareFn.

```js
const json = [
    {
        adjustmnetfileds: [
            'some data',
            'some data',
        ],
        adjustments: [
            {
                approvedByName: 'Jack',
                taskName: 'Insurance',
                approvedStatus: 1,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        adjustmnetfileds: [
            'some data',
            'some data',
        ],
        adjustments: [
            {
                approvedByName: 'Dan',
                taskName: 'Insurance-Test',
                approvedStatus: 3,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        adjustmnetfileds: [
            'some data',
            'some data',
        ],
        adjustments: [
            {
                approvedByName: 'Sam',
                taskName: 'Insurance-Test',
                approvedStatus: 2,
            }
        ]
    },
]

// This sorts into ASC order
json.sort((a, b) => a.adjustments[0].approvedStatus  - b.adjustments[0].approvedStatus);

// For sorting into DESC order
// json.sort((a, b) => b.adjustments[0].approvedStatus  - a.adjustments[0].approvedStatus);

console.log(json);
```

I hope, your JSON structure is correct.

> Note that the array is sorted in place, and no copy is made.

If you want new array, then copy first and then apply sort on that.

```js
const originalArr = [1, 2, 3]
const copied = [...originalArr]
```

Comment: Hi, this code is not working. I have edited my question and added the snapshot with the correct JSON structure. Could you please open up the snapshot once again. The JSON contains 16 entries and then sub-entries

Comment: Please open the first attached snapshot and let me know how to sort according to approvedStatus field.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/16601528)

You can use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Example :

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.approvedStatus < b.approvedStatus) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.approvedStatus > b.approvedStatus) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

let data: Array<{ field: any, approvedStatus: number }> = [{ field: {}, approvedStatus: 2 }, { field: {}, approvedStatus: 1 }]
data.sort(compare);
```